# Does a broadcasted state in the observer vault get updated if the original state changes?

Tags: corda

When an initiator broadcasted a newly issued state to an observer the first time, and if the initiator change the state i/e to `APPROVED` without a broadcast flow.

Would the observer get to know about the state changes if it is not a participant of the state? The Observer concept only works if every changes made is broadcasted?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Each transaction would need to be broadcast to keep the observer up-to-date.